# I am trying to find the gregorian dates that are equivalent to Elul 29. but only those that close the 7-year Shemitah cycle since 2008

Tags: shmita, elul

I only need those that close the 7-year shmita cycle since 2008. This question is to do more research on the possibility that the messiah has been identified and prophesies in Isaiah are being fulfilled.

Answer (score 1):

There are many applications that will convert a Hebrew date to a Gregorian date. One that will print you lots of possibilities is [this one](https://stevemorse.org/jcal/whendid.html) by Stephen Morse. You can ask it "When did (or will) Elul 29 fall on any day of the week between January 1 and December 31?" If you restrict the search to years between 5700 and 5899, you get:

```
Elul 29, 5700 [CL] = October 2, 1940 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5701 [NC] = September 21, 1941 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5702 [CC] = September 11, 1942 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5703 [DL] = September 29, 1943 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5704 [NC] = September 17, 1944 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5705 [CC] = September 7, 1945 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5706 [DL] = September 25, 1946 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5707 [NC] = September 14, 1947 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5708 [CL] = October 3, 1948 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5709 [CC] = September 23, 1949 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5710 [DC] = September 11, 1950 CE (Monday)
Elul 29, 5711 [NL] = September 30, 1951 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5712 [CC] = September 19, 1952 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5713 [CC] = September 9, 1953 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5714 [DL] = September 27, 1954 CE (Monday)
Elul 29, 5715 [NC] = September 16, 1955 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5716 [CC] = September 5, 1956 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5717 [CL] = September 25, 1957 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5718 [NC] = September 14, 1958 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5719 [DL] = October 2, 1959 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5720 [CC] = September 21, 1960 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5721 [NC] = September 10, 1961 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5722 [DL] = September 28, 1962 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5723 [CC] = September 18, 1963 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5724 [NC] = September 6, 1964 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5725 [CL] = September 26, 1965 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5726 [DC] = September 14, 1966 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5727 [CL] = October 4, 1967 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5728 [NC] = September 22, 1968 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5729 [CC] = September 12, 1969 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5730 [DL] = September 30, 1970 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5731 [NC] = September 19, 1971 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5732 [CC] = September 8, 1972 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5733 [DL] = September 26, 1973 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5734 [CC] = September 16, 1974 CE (Monday)
Elul 29, 5735 [NC] = September 5, 1975 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5736 [CL] = September 24, 1976 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5737 [DC] = September 12, 1977 CE (Monday)
Elul 29, 5738 [NL] = October 1, 1978 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5739 [CC] = September 21, 1979 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5740 [CC] = September 10, 1980 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5741 [DL] = September 28, 1981 CE (Monday)
Elul 29, 5742 [NC] = September 17, 1982 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5743 [CC] = September 7, 1983 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5744 [CL] = September 26, 1984 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5745 [NC] = September 15, 1985 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5746 [DL] = October 3, 1986 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5747 [CC] = September 23, 1987 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5748 [NC] = September 11, 1988 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5749 [DL] = September 29, 1989 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5750 [CC] = September 19, 1990 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5751 [NC] = September 8, 1991 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5752 [CL] = September 27, 1992 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5753 [DC] = September 15, 1993 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5754 [CC] = September 5, 1994 CE (Monday)
Elul 29, 5755 [NL] = September 24, 1995 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5756 [CC] = September 13, 1996 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5757 [DL] = October 1, 1997 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5758 [NC] = September 20, 1998 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5759 [CC] = September 10, 1999 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5760 [CL] = September 29, 2000 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5761 [DC] = September 17, 2001 CE (Monday)
Elul 29, 5762 [NC] = September 6, 2002 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5763 [CL] = September 26, 2003 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5764 [CC] = September 15, 2004 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5765 [DL] = October 3, 2005 CE (Monday)
Elul 29, 5766 [NC] = September 22, 2006 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5767 [CC] = September 12, 2007 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5768 [DL] = September 29, 2008 CE (Monday)
Elul 29, 5769 [NC] = September 18, 2009 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5770 [CC] = September 8, 2010 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5771 [CL] = September 28, 2011 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5772 [NC] = September 16, 2012 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5773 [DC] = September 4, 2013 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5774 [CL] = September 24, 2014 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5775 [NC] = September 13, 2015 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5776 [CL] = October 2, 2016 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5777 [DC] = September 20, 2017 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5778 [NC] = September 9, 2018 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5779 [CL] = September 29, 2019 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5780 [CC] = September 18, 2020 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5781 [DC] = September 6, 2021 CE (Monday)
Elul 29, 5782 [NL] = September 25, 2022 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5783 [CC] = September 15, 2023 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5784 [DL] = October 2, 2024 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5785 [CC] = September 22, 2025 CE (Monday)
Elul 29, 5786 [NC] = September 11, 2026 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5787 [CL] = October 1, 2027 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5788 [CC] = September 20, 2028 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5789 [NC] = September 9, 2029 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5790 [DL] = September 27, 2030 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5791 [CC] = September 17, 2031 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5792 [NC] = September 5, 2032 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5793 [DL] = September 23, 2033 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5794 [CC] = September 13, 2034 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5795 [CL] = October 3, 2035 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5796 [NC] = September 21, 2036 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5797 [DC] = September 9, 2037 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5798 [CL] = September 29, 2038 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5799 [NC] = September 18, 2039 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5800 [CC] = September 7, 2040 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5801 [DL] = September 25, 2041 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5802 [NC] = September 14, 2042 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5803 [CL] = October 4, 2043 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5804 [DC] = September 21, 2044 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5805 [CC] = September 11, 2045 CE (Monday)
Elul 29, 5806 [NL] = September 30, 2046 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5807 [CC] = September 20, 2047 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5808 [DC] = September 7, 2048 CE (Monday)
Elul 29, 5809 [NL] = September 26, 2049 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5810 [CC] = September 16, 2050 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5811 [CC] = September 6, 2051 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5812 [DL] = September 23, 2052 CE (Monday)
Elul 29, 5813 [NC] = September 12, 2053 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5814 [CL] = October 2, 2054 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5815 [CC] = September 22, 2055 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5816 [NC] = September 10, 2056 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5817 [DL] = September 28, 2057 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5818 [CC] = September 18, 2058 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5819 [NC] = September 7, 2059 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5820 [DL] = September 24, 2060 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5821 [CC] = September 14, 2061 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5822 [CL] = October 4, 2062 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5823 [NC] = September 23, 2063 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5824 [DC] = September 10, 2064 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5825 [CL] = September 30, 2065 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5826 [NC] = September 19, 2066 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5827 [CC] = September 9, 2067 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5828 [DL] = September 26, 2068 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5829 [NC] = September 15, 2069 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5830 [CC] = September 5, 2070 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5831 [DL] = September 23, 2071 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5832 [CC] = September 12, 2072 CE (Monday)
Elul 29, 5833 [NL] = October 1, 2073 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5834 [CC] = September 21, 2074 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5835 [DC] = September 9, 2075 CE (Monday)
Elul 29, 5836 [NL] = September 27, 2076 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5837 [CC] = September 17, 2077 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5838 [CC] = September 7, 2078 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5839 [DL] = September 25, 2079 CE (Monday)
Elul 29, 5840 [NC] = September 13, 2080 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5841 [CL] = October 3, 2081 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5842 [CC] = September 23, 2082 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5843 [NC] = September 12, 2083 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5844 [DL] = September 29, 2084 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5845 [CC] = September 19, 2085 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5846 [NC] = September 8, 2086 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5847 [DL] = September 26, 2087 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5848 [CC] = September 15, 2088 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5849 [NC] = September 4, 2089 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5850 [CL] = September 24, 2090 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5851 [DC] = September 12, 2091 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5852 [CL] = October 1, 2092 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5853 [NC] = September 20, 2093 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5854 [CC] = September 10, 2094 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5855 [DL] = September 28, 2095 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5856 [NC] = September 16, 2096 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5857 [CC] = September 6, 2097 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5858 [CL] = September 26, 2098 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5859 [DC] = September 14, 2099 CE (Monday)
Elul 29, 5860 [NL] = October 3, 2100 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5861 [CC] = September 23, 2101 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5862 [CC] = September 13, 2102 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5863 [DL] = October 1, 2103 CE (Monday)
Elul 29, 5864 [NC] = September 19, 2104 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5865 [CC] = September 9, 2105 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5866 [CL] = September 29, 2106 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5867 [NC] = September 18, 2107 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5868 [DC] = September 5, 2108 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5869 [CL] = September 25, 2109 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5870 [NC] = September 14, 2110 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5871 [DL] = October 2, 2111 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5872 [CC] = September 21, 2112 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5873 [NC] = September 10, 2113 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5874 [CL] = September 30, 2114 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5875 [DC] = September 18, 2115 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5876 [NC] = September 6, 2116 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5877 [CL] = September 26, 2117 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5878 [CC] = September 16, 2118 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5879 [DL] = October 4, 2119 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5880 [NC] = September 22, 2120 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5881 [CC] = September 12, 2121 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5882 [DL] = September 30, 2122 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5883 [CC] = September 20, 2123 CE (Monday)
Elul 29, 5884 [NC] = September 8, 2124 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5885 [CL] = September 28, 2125 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5886 [CC] = September 18, 2126 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5887 [NC] = September 7, 2127 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5888 [DL] = September 24, 2128 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5889 [CC] = September 14, 2129 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5890 [DL] = October 2, 2130 CE (Monday)
Elul 29, 5891 [NC] = September 21, 2131 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5892 [CC] = September 10, 2132 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5893 [CL] = September 30, 2133 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5894 [NC] = September 19, 2134 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5895 [DC] = September 7, 2135 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5896 [CL] = September 26, 2136 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5897 [NC] = September 15, 2137 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5898 [DL] = October 3, 2138 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5899 [CC] = September 23, 2139 CE (Wednesday)
```

If we restrict to ends of shemitta cycles since 2008, we get:

```
Elul 29, 5768 [DL] = September 29, 2008 CE (Monday)
Elul 29, 5775 [NC] = September 13, 2015 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5782 [NL] = September 25, 2022 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5789 [NC] = September 9, 2029 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5796 [NC] = September 21, 2036 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5803 [CL] = October 4, 2043 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5810 [CC] = September 16, 2050 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5817 [DL] = September 28, 2057 CE (Friday)
Elul 29, 5824 [DC] = September 10, 2064 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5831 [DL] = September 23, 2071 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5838 [CC] = September 7, 2078 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5845 [CC] = September 19, 2085 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5852 [CL] = October 1, 2092 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5859 [DC] = September 14, 2099 CE (Monday)
Elul 29, 5866 [CL] = September 29, 2106 CE (Wednesday)
Elul 29, 5873 [NC] = September 10, 2113 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5880 [NC] = September 22, 2120 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5887 [NC] = September 7, 2127 CE (Sunday)
Elul 29, 5894 [NC] = September 19, 2134 CE (Sunday)
```

You can generate many more if you want, up to Jewish year 9999. Note that the Jewish day actually starts on the evening preceding the listed Gregorian day, and the end of the listed Gregorian day is actually the first of Tishrei.

Caveat: we hope for the return of the Sanhedrin and return to [establishing the new moon via witnesses](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Sanctification_of_the_New_Month.5.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). In that eventuality, these dates may no longer be accurate.